# Why is my Extension Method not showing up in my test class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, extension-methods

I created an extension method called `HasContentPermission` on the `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity`:

```
namespace System.Security.Principal
{
    public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static bool HasContentPermission
            (this IIdentity identity, int contentID)
        {
            // I do stuff here
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
bool hasPermission = User.Identity.HasPermission(contentID);
```

Works like a charm.  Now I want to unit test it.  To do that, all I really need to do is call the extension method directly, so:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace MyUnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void HasContentPermission_PermissionRecordExists_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        IIdentity identity;
        bool result = identity.HasContentPermission(...
```

But `HasContentPermission` won't intellisense.  I tried creating a stub class that inherits from `IIdentity`, but that didn't work either.  Why?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Your syntax in the first code block is wrong - you can't define a method in a namespace scope... Can you put in your actual code?

Comment: Are you sure your test project is referencing the assembly that your Extension Method lives in (rather than just the namespace)?

Comment: @Reed: I edited the question to add the missing code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make sure you've:

1. made the class static
2. made the class accessible to the calling code
3. included `this` before the type to extend
4. built the project containing the extension
5. added a reference to the project in your unit test project
6. added a `using myns;` to any source file that uses the extension method if your extension method is contained inside a different namespace

Note that you've also got (I assume) a typo in your example in that the method isn't in a class.

Finally, I would avoid putting methods into the official .NET namespaces. It can only be confusing to anyone coming after you who might think that the method is an officially supported method when in reality it is your own and contained within your project.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add a reference to the main project in the test project. I always forget to do that. For some reason I always assume that, because both projects are in the same solution, that they are aware of each other.

Comment: While you're right on the facts, I have to disagree with your opinion about extending framework classes.  This is their *primary* purpose.

Comment: @Steven - It's fine to extend framework classes. What's bad is putting those extensions in the framework namespace.

Comment: I would put them in a `MyProject.SecurityExtensions` namespace as well and that putting them in the .Net framework classes would be misleading. You have no way to know that is your custom extensions without going to the source. If it is in your own namespace, just hovering over it tells you it's bespoke.

Comment: @Steven - I'm not arguing that you shouldn't use extension methods to .NET framework classes.  I just wouldn't put them in an official namespace.  I'd use my own.

Comment: @Mark: OK, but what if they are aspect-oriented, general purpose extensions?  Putting them into your own specific project namespace (unless it's a library of extensions) wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @Greg, tvan: Point taken regarding the namespace; I misread it as referring to the class being extended.  Mea culpa.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: We have a `MyCompany.Core` assembly we carry around on all our projects. We put our extensions in there. If I hovered over a method that said "System.Security.Principal.DoSomething" I would expect to find DoSomething here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.aspx. If it said MyCompany.Core.SecurityExtensions.DoSomethig, I would know exactly where it is. I also would be more likely to CTRL+Click to get to the source if I knew we wrote it.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the `using`. I've done this a couple of times, when I've put all the extension methods into a single static class in my own package and then wondered why they didnt appear in the usual place..

Comment: They're **your** aspect-oriented, general purpose extensions. Putting them somewhere other than `System` makes perfect sense.

Comment: My issue was that I did have the namespace referenced, but it was also ALIASED - i.e.  using xyz = mynamespace.whateves;   Once I used the namespace corresponding to the extension methods, VS was happy and everything compiled.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that you added an extension method to the existing `System.Security.Principal` namespace. Make sure that you reference the project that defines the extension method, or try it with a different namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The extension method should be in a static class. Where is your static class? Does your code compile?

Answer (score 0):

I could find very little documentation on Unit Testing for VB.NET. I had to discover by trial and error that, by default, Extension Methods in VB.NET only work in the current assembly. This is because a static class in VB.NET is a Module and Module scope defaults to "Friend" (Internal).

Use "Public Module" if you want to unit test your Extension Methods in a project referenced in a Unit Test project.