# Why is my extension method not working?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an extension method

```
public static class DbMigratorExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> DoCoolStuff(this DbMigrator dbMigrator, string[] first, string[] second)
    {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to use it like

```
DbMigrator.DoCoolStuff
```

but I get the

> ```
> 'DbMigrator' does not contain a definition for ...
> ```

I have followed all the bullet points on

[Why is my Extension Method not showing up in my test class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525205/why-is-my-extension-method-not-showing-up-in-my-test-class)

Also I will note that VS recognizes

```
DbMigratorExtensions.DoCoolStuff
```

so I'm not sure why it isn't working as an extension method.

Comment: make sure to put the `using` statement on top of your cs file. what namespace does `DbMigratorExtensions` belong to?

Comment: The using statement is there (That's how it recognizes DbMigratorExtensions.DoCoolStuff)

Comment: then make sure `DbMigrator` is not a type and its a variable. c# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extension methods work on object instances, not types.

So you need to change

```
DbMigrator.DoCoolStuff(...);
```

to

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator();
var stringList = migrator.DoCoolStuff(...);
```

If `DoCoolStuff()` doesn't *need* an instance, it should not be an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a static extension method, C# does not currently support this.  You can only make non-static extension methods.  This will probably change at some point.